# How to append fields in mule dataweave to existing json payload

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Exisiting Json
{
a:1,
b:2
}

Add the field
c:3

Final Output expected
{
a:1,
b:2,
c:3
}

Answer (score 2):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---

{ a:1, b:2 } ++ {c: 3}
```

Sample Output:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly keep payload as it is and add the new JSON field as below:

```
payload ++ {c:3}

output:
{ 
 a:1,
 b:2, 
 c:3 
}
```

Comment: In the future, it's best to use code blocks to distinguish code portions of your answer

Comment: sure @JonathonAnderson